# Messages taking a long time to appear

Tags: ios, iphone

When I receive a message there will immediately be a notification, however when opening the Messages app, the message will usually take about 5 seconds before it appears.

If there a known issue with the OS or a quick fix for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iMessage and iCloud have lots of issues with delivery, sync, and reliability. There's no fix, but you can always [write feedback to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) or [file a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/) (free developer account required).

Comment: This might be as close as we will get to an answer. Thank you Kevin :)